# img tag src attribute getting dummy html url in php html dom

Tags: php, image, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, src

I am new in PHP I am working on data scrapping I am using simple_html_dom.php

i have fetch data from table. table have images which i have to fetch images url

below is my code

```
$html->find("tr[class='zzz'], tr[class='sss']"); 
foreach($items as $post) {
  echo $post->children(1)->children(0)->src;
}
```

I checked all of the way to get src attribute but output is showing is

> test_files/f197a4484b004dfb9c98a866c40cf249.html

original url is like that

> ../img/photo/f197a4484b004dfb9c98a866c40cf249.thumb.jpg

so any body can help me

Thanks

Comment: provide snippet of the html you want to scrape

Comment: <td align="center">
                            <img onmouseover="Large(this)" src="../img/photo/f197a4484b004dfb9c98a866c40cf249.thumb.jpg" style="width:65px;border-width:0px;">
                        </td>

Comment: I am getting style attributes exactly but issue in src

Comment: for brevity, try this first: `foreach($html->find('img') as $element)  echo $element->src;`

Comment: I tried that but getting same result

Comment: share the url and i'll check

Comment: I have local html page i am fetching from data in local html page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166460/discussion-between-codekaizer-and-bhautikmewada191).

Answer (score -1):

problem is solved it.

I think its problem about my local html file

I have php file using this file

I recreate html file locally and its working !!!

Thanks